# Is it possible to always load a custom style sheet for a certain website in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm reading the guide/documentation for Android at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html on Google Chrome on Windows.

I have made certain changes with Chrome Developer Tools like

- Changed body background to grey
- Changed monospaced font from courier new to consolas

for easier reading. For some reason this site doesn't obey Chrome font setting rules, even though other sites do. So I have to manually go in and change the monospace font from courier new to consolas.

But these changes go away as soon as the page is reloaded. Is it possible to make these changes permanent ?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the settings > Show Advanced Settings> Web Content> Customize fonts. I am on mac but there should be something equivalent to pc. Also, to run your own css, just use any extension from the web store. One of the many is [Style Chooser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/style-chooser/daodklicmmjhcacgkjpianadkdkbkbce?hl=en#)